# Knockout observableArray is not binding correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I am in the process of learning about knockout/json/mvc et al and have tried to put together an example project, but for some reason I am unable to get the data to bind correctly.

In the code snippet below, I get some JSON data from a web server and then try to map it to a function and then eventually to my knockout observableArray. What I then do is use this observableArray to bind to a HTML table. However the HTML table is not displaying any data. I put a label on to the HTML page and this **does** print out but with a toString() value of :
`[Object object]`
five times, which matches the amount of properties in the JSON data.

Can anyone see anything obvious I am missing?

JSON received from web server:

```
{ "Id": 1, "Name": "Inst123", "Price": 10, "DateTime": "2014-01-16T17:22:43.6383507+00:00", "Description": "Descriptions" };
```

.

ViewModel

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var gtViewModel = new GvTradeViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(gtViewModel);
    console.log("ViewModel created");
});

    var GvTradeViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.gvTrades = ko.observableArray([]);

    var apiUrl = "http://localhost:57858/api/Trade/1";

    console.log("Starting JSON data retrieval from: " + apiUrl);

    $.getJSON(apiUrl)
       // Handle success event.
      .done(function (jsonData) {
          if (jsonData.isEmptyObject)
              console.log("NoData recieved");
          else {
              console.log("JSON data: " + jsonData);

              var mappedTrades = $.map(jsonData, function (gvTradeData) {
                  return new GvTrade(gvTradeData);
              });
              self.gvTrades(mappedTrades);
              console.log(self.gvTrades);

          }
      })
      // Handle error/fail event.
     .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
         var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
         console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
     });
};

function GvTrade(data) {
    this.TradeId = ko.observable(data.TradeId);
    this.InstrumentName = ko.observable(data.InstrumentName);
    this.DateTime = ko.observable(data.DateTime);
    this.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
    this.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>TradeId</th>
        <th>InstrumentName</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>DateTime</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $data.gvTrades">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: InstrumentName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Price"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: DateTime"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Not sure why you have `$data` there. Just `foreach: gvTrades` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON coming from your server represents **a single object** and not an array.

So when you are calling `$.map` then it does not correctly maps your data as an array, so you will end up some unusable objects.

To fix this you need to make sure that your `jsonData` containing an array before the map operation, you can do this with calling [`jQuery.makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) on it (or you can have an `if` which is based on your data type decide whether you need to map or not):

```
var mappedTrades = $.map($.makeArray(jsonData), function (gvTradeData) {
    return new GvTrade(gvTradeData);
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chdD8/).